# How do I make the whole program stop completely after 5 tries (clicks)

Tags: python, onclick, python-turtle

How do I make the whole program stop compleatly after 5 trys (click) doesn't matter are they are on turtle or not, but the program after writing you are out of trys should break and when pressed dont put black or red dot just do nothing. Here is the code:

```
from turtle import *
from random import *
import time
reset()


penup() 
hideturtle() 
speed(0)


bandymai = 0 #tries
taskai = 0   #points
info = Turtle() 
info.penup()
info.goto(-180, 160) 
info.color("Blue") 

def gaudom(x, y):
    goto(x, y)
    if distance(beglys.pos()) < 10:
        color('red') #hit color
        global taskai
        global bandymai
        taskai = taskai + 1
        info.clear()
        info.write(taskai, font = ("Arial", 20, "bold"))
        bandymai = bandymai + 1
     else:
        color('black') #miss color 
        dot(20)
        bandymai = bandymai + 1

screen = getscreen()
screen.onclick( gaudom )


beglys = Turtle()
beglys.color('green')
beglys.shape('square')


for n in range(100):
    x = randint(-200, 200) 
    y = randint(-200, 200) 
    beglys.penup()
    beglys.clear() 
    beglys.goto(x, y)
    time.sleep(1) 
    if taskai == 3:
        info.write('you win!!!', font = ("Arial", 80, "bold"))
        break
    elif bandymai == 5:
        info.write('you are out of trys', font = ("Arial", 50, "bold"))
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 2 lines at the end of your code.

```
screen.onclick(None) #Do nothing when clicking the screen.

screen.mainloop()    #Must be last statement in a turtle graphics program.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a band-aid on the code, let's take it a apart and reconstruct it in an event-compatible way (i.e. turtle timer events instead of `time.sleep()`).  We'll also make the *implicit* default turtle *explicit*, remove several no-ops, and generally tweak the style:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

bandymai = 0  # tries
taskai = 0  # points

def gaudom(x, y):
    global taskai, bandymai

    screen.onclick(None)  # disable handler inside handler

    turtle.goto(x, y)

    if turtle.distance(beglys.pos()) < 10:
        taskai += 1
        info.clear()
        info.write(taskai, font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'))
    else:
        turtle.color('black')  # miss color
        turtle.dot(20)

    bandymai += 1

    screen.onclick(gaudom)  # reenable handler

ticks = 100

def play():
    global ticks

    x = randint(-200, 200)
    y = randint(-200, 200)

    beglys.goto(x, y)

    if taskai == 3:
        screen.onclick(None)  # Do nothing when clicking the screen.
        info.write("You win!", font=('Arial', 80, 'bold'))
        return

    if bandymai == 5:
        screen.onclick(None)  # Do nothing when clicking the screen.
        info.write("You are out of trys.", font=('Arial', 50, 'bold'))
        return

    ticks -= 1
    if ticks:
        screen.ontimer(play, 1000)  # 1 second (1000 milliseconds)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()

info = Turtle()
info.color('blue')
info.penup()
info.goto(-180, 160)

beglys = Turtle()
beglys.color('green')
beglys.shape('square')
beglys.penup()

screen.onclick(gaudom)

play()

screen.mainloop()  # Must be last statement in a turtle graphics program.
```